# Rust give ownership of part of vector to each thread

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a use case where I want to offload some computation to a `ThreadPool` in Rust.

Each thread needs a read-only reference to the ith element in the vector.
After the thread pool has finished processing all the data, I want to modify the vector's contents based on the computation result.

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Barrier};

use threadpool::ThreadPool;

fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..10 {
        data.push(format!("data {}", i));
    }

    let pool = ThreadPool::new(4);
    let barrier = Arc::new(Barrier::new(10));

    loop {
        // Wait for user input
    
        // Perform computation using threadpool
        for i in 0..data.len() {
            let barrier = barrier.clone();
            let readonly_data: Arc<String> = Arc::new(data[i].clone());
            pool.execute(move || {
                println!("data[{}] = {}", i, readonly_data);
                barrier.wait();
            });
        }
        barrier.wait();
        
        // Modify data after threadpool is finished
        data[2] = "data modified".to_string();
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I receive an error:

```
let readonly_data: Arc<String> = Arc::new(data[i]);
   |                                      ^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

However, I don't want to copy each item. I just want a separate lifetime for each item in the vector tied to the thread's lifetime, and then after the threadpool is finished, regain control of the vector. How can I tell the compiler this?

Comment: It's very likely you want to use something like [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/) which handles exactly that.

Comment: If you clone the elements anyway, why do you need `Arc`?

Comment: Your `Barrier` is wrong; it should be 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to add one to the barrier since the main thread also waits. (thanks to a comment from Chayim)

```rs
let barrier = Arc::new(Barrier::new(11));
```

For purely reading the data, you can achieve this by converting `data` into `Arc<[String]>` (this also works for `Arc<Vec<String>>` which has less creation overhead, but `Arc<[String]>` has less redirection during use). You can then cheaply clone `data` and move each clone into the closure. I've replaced your threadpool with [`thread::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) to get something that works. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=35621054382fd8868a0fa69670beb0db)

```rs
let data: Arc<[String]> = data.into();

// Perform computation using threadpool
for i in 0..data.len() {
    let barrier = barrier.clone();
    let data = data.clone();
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let readonly_data = &data[i];
        println!("data[{}] = {}", i, readonly_data);
        barrier.wait();
    });
}
barrier.wait();
```

However, this doesn't let you mutate it after. Rust isn't able to statically verify that all threads will be finished by the time you try writing to it.

You can fix this in 4 different ways.

## Unwrapping the `Arc`

You can return the `Arc` to a `Vec` in various ways, but in order to avoid cloning all the data, you would need to unwrap the `Arc`. While you can convert a `Vec<T>` into `Arc<[T]>`, I couldn't find a way to go the other way around, even to `Box<[T]>`, so I've just used `Arc<Vec<T>>`. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d291bd64b30a74724d59b2a4bba27632)

```rs
let data: Arc<Vec<String>> = data.into();

// Perform computation using threadpool
for i in 0..data.len() {
    let barrier = barrier.clone();
    let data = data.clone();
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let readonly_data = &data[i];
        println!("data[{}] = {}", i, readonly_data);
        drop(data); // Ensure `data` is dropped before the barrier
        barrier.wait();
    });
}
barrier.wait();

// Unwrap the Arc
let mut data = Arc::into_inner(data).unwrap();
// Modify data after threadpool is finished
data[2] = "data modified".to_string();
```

This relies on providing the right number to `barrier` to avoid panicking, so I don't recommend it.

## Runtime borrow checking

`RwLock` allows you to move borrow checking to runtime, allowing you to use runtime procedures—like `barrier.wait()` and `RwLock`'s blocking locking methods—to ensure you mutate the data when you intend to and without data races. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e96b57eac7d3ac04a6868c26177f9406)

```rs
let data: Arc<RwLock<Vec<String>>> = RwLock::new(data).into();

// Perform computation using threadpool
let len = data.read().unwrap().len();
for i in 0..len {
    let barrier = barrier.clone();
    let data = data.clone();
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        // This block ensures the lock is dropped before calling `barrier.wait()`
        {
            let lock = data.read().unwrap();
            let readonly_data = &lock[i];
            println!("data[{}] = {}", i, readonly_data);
        }
        barrier.wait();
    });
}
barrier.wait();

// Modify data after threadpool is finished
let mut data = data.write().unwrap();
data[2] = "data modified".to_string();
```

Similar to the one above, this relies on the correct `barrier` number, this time to avoid incorrect results. The last two methods do away with the barrier, avoiding the possibility of making this mistake. They also remove the need to change the data storage, improving performance.

## Scoped threads

This is the simplest answer, and you can wrap this behavior in your `ThreadPool` if you wish, but you cannot keep the threads alive while you mutate `data`. This is fine if you only need the threadpool once, but if you want to use it multiple times, you will need to spawn new threads each time. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a25bf19440a201990152cd318cf6517c)

```rs
// Perform computation using threadpool
std::thread::scope(|scope| {
    for i in 0..data.len() {
        let readonly_data = &data[i];
        scope.spawn(move || {
            println!("data[{}] = {}", i, readonly_data);
        });
    }
});

// Modify data after threadpool is finished
data[2] = "data modified".to_string();
```

## Rayon

[Rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/) is a library that allows you to run any iterator in parallel. It combines the advantages of a threadpool (doesn't spawn a thread for every task, reusable threads) with the advantages of scoped threads (no clones or `Arc`). [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8766a2123e6ba67433a37bdff6819eb8)

```rs
// Perform computation using threadpool
(0..data.len()).into_par_iter().for_each(|i| {
    let readonly_data = &data[i];
    println!("data[{}] = {}", i, readonly_data);
});

// Modify data after threadpool is finished
data[2] = "data modified".to_string();
```

Rayon uses unsafe code internally to allow such usage.

Since your data is already conveniently in an iterable container, you can simplify your loop to use `data` itself as the iterator.

```rs
data.par_iter().enumerate().for_each(|(i, readonly_data)| {
    println!("data[{}] = {}", i, readonly_data);
});
```

## Final version

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d122a3c595600834beafdd1a9a9e1cc5)

```rs
use rayon::iter::{IndexedParallelIterator, IntoParallelRefIterator, ParallelIterator};

fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..10 {
        data.push(format!("data {}", i));
    }

    // Perform computation using threadpool
    data.par_iter().enumerate().for_each(|(i, readonly_data)| {
        println!("data[{}] = {}", i, readonly_data);
    });

    // Modify data after threadpool is finished
    data[2] = "data modified".to_string();

    println!("{data:?}");
}
```

Comment: It panics because the `Barrier` is wrong: it needs to be 11.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman you're absolutely right, which means one thread never terminates, and possibly (but probably never in reality) the main thread deadlocks.

Comment: No, all it means is that `main()` resumes after nine threads have finished, without waiting for the tenth.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yeah but then the eleventh thread calls `wait` and is stuck there until 9 other threads call it, which never happens. If the tenth thread is the main thread, it's stuck forever.